# Two implementations of the same interface in Autofac's JSON configuration

Tags: autofac, autofac-configuration

I need to enable late-binding in an application and I want to have an option to explicitly configure services using JSON configuration file.

I have an interface `IDependency` and two classes `DependencyOne` and `DependencyTwo` which both implement the interface. I also have a `SomeService` class that has a constructor with following signature:

```
public SomeService(IDependency dependency1, IDependency dependency2)
```

I want to inject `DependencyOne` for `dependency1`, and `DependencyTwo` for `dependency2`.

How can I configure that purely in JSON configuration, without using any attributes in the code? Is it possible at all?

The no-attribute requirement is needed because the late-bound assembly is not supposed to depend on AutoFac.

Thanks in advance.

**Update: solution**

Travis' answer below contains a link to FAQ which led me to acceptable solution. Use "marker" interfaces, e.g. `IDependencyOne : IDependency` and `IDependencyTwo : IDependency`, and then `SomeService(IDependencyOne dependency1, IDependencyTwo dependency2)`. The thing I don't like so much is that now a generic decorator for `IDependency` needs to implement all markers, say `LoggingDecorator : IDependencyOne, IDependencyTwo` if I want to use it in `SomeService`, but as long as the markers stay empty, that's not a big problem. This way I don't have to enforce dependency on Autofac's dlls in the late-bound assembly, while still have DI configured in JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two different implementations of the same interface that can't be treated the same, that's a code smell. [There is an FAQ about ways to work around that](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) but the short answer is **you won't literally be able to specify two different instances of the same interface like this without some manual work.** There isn't a mechanism for easily wiring this up because it's a design problem.

Take a moment to read [the FAQ](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) to see why and additional ideas for how to solve this beyond just what I'm showing here.

However, let's assume you can't change the interface `IDependency` since usually that's the sticking point for folks. Let's also assume you can't just put `DependencyOne` and `DependencyTwo` right in the constructor for... whatever reason. (Both of those would be the first place I'd look to resolve this rather than trying to complicate my DI wire-up, but again, let's say for the sake of argument that's not an option.)

I would probably register each instance in config with a metadata key that can be used later.

```
{
  "components": [{
    "type": "MyAssembly.DependencyOne, MyAssembly",
    "services": [{
      "type": "MyAssembly.IDependency, MyAssembly"
    }],
    "metadata": [{
      "key": "type",
      "value": "One",
      "type": "System.String, mscorlib"
    }]
  }, {
    "type": "MyAssembly.DependencyTwo, MyAssembly",
    "services": [{
      "type": "MyAssembly.IDependency, MyAssembly"
    }],
    "metadata": [{
      "key": "type",
      "value": "Two",
      "type": "System.String, mscorlib"
    }]
  }]
}
```

OK, so we have two components that each expose the same interface, and each has a metadata key of `One` or `Two` respectively.

[In your class you can use that metadata.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html)

```cs
public class SomeService
{
  readonly IEnumerable<Meta<IDependency>> _dependencies;

  public SomeService(IEnumerable<Meta<IDependency>> dependencies)
  {
    _dependencies = dependencies;
  }

  public void DoSomething(string parameter)
  {
    var dep = _dependencies.First(a => a.Metadata["type"].Equals(parameter));
    dep.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

The idea is that you can choose the appropriate thing using the metadata. Obviously adapt that to your own needs; maybe it's not a parameter from the caller but something in your code elsewhere; the concept still holds.

Again, though, I can't recommend strongly enough that you [check out the FAQ](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) and **strongly consider a redesign to avoid this situation entirely**. It will make your life and the lives of your fellow developers easier in the long run.

Comment: Thanks. FAQ contains the answer. The metadata would almost work, but it imposes dependency on Autofac. I can live with Autofac's JSON syntax in the configuration - theoretically I can write my own parser if I need to change the container (I wouldn't - I love Autofac). So I guess "marker" interfaces is a viable option, even though it means any generic decorator will need to implement all of the markers. But that's alright. I admit this issue is more theoretical than practical. Btw. background is I want to provide plugin support with DI but without forcing dependency on Autofac.